# Textblock array get Text when tapped

Tags: c#, wpf, events, textblock

I created a Textblock array (for a create keyboard). I would like get the Textblock Text when I tapped one Textblock.

```
keyboardButtons[i] = new TextBlock();
keyboardButtons[i].Width = 45;
keyboardButtons[i].Height = 55;
keyboardButtons[i].Text = alphabet.Substring(i, 1);
keyboardButtons[i].Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
keyboardButtons[i].FontSize = 25.0;
keyboardButtons[i].TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
Canvas.SetLeft(keyboardButtons[i], xPos);
Canvas.SetTop(keyboardButtons[i], yPos);
RectCanvas.Children.Add(keyboardButtons[i]);

keyboardButtons[i].Tapped += new TappedEventHandler(ButtonTap);
```

Tapped method:

```
void ButtonTap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

What should I write in ButtonTap method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **Button control** for this was a better choice. You can pass the alphabet as the TAG property of the Button control.

Following image shows Button B being pressed (just for example). You can always add your own logic to that.

[image]

**Code behind C# file**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    char Key = 'A';

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Tag = Key + i;

        button.FontSize = 40;

        button.Width = 100;
        button.Height = 100;

        button.Content = (char)(Key + i);
        button.Click += button_Click;

        stackPanel1.Children.Add(button);
    }

    for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Tag = Key + i;

        button.FontSize = 40;

        button.Width = 100;
        button.Height = 100;

        button.Content = (char)(Key + i);
        button.Click += button_Click;

        stackPanel2.Children.Add(button);
    }

    for (int i = 20; i < 26; i++)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Tag = Key + i;

        button.FontSize = 40;

        button.Width = 100;
        button.Height = 100;

        button.Content = (char)(Key + i);
        button.Click += button_Click;

        stackPanel3.Children.Add(button);
    }
}

//Now use a switch case to get the TAG property
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var t = (sender as Button).Tag;

    char tag = Convert.ToChar(t);

    switch (tag)
    {
    case 'A':

        console.Text = "You typed " + tag;

        //Your code logic
        break;

    case 'B':

        console.Text = "You typed " + tag;

        //Your code logic
        break;

    case 'C':

        console.Text = "You typed " + tag;

        //Your code logic
        break;

//Rest of the alphabets
    }
}
```

**XAML file**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="40, 200, 20, 20">
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel1" Orientation="Horizontal">

        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel2" Orientation="Horizontal">

        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel3" Orientation="Horizontal">

        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="console" Height="100" Width="1000" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="50" Text="Press a Button"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This is a really good idea! I will use your solution. Thank you!

Comment: And can I change buttons size? I tried "button.Width" and "button.Height", but not working. Every buttons have a fix size.

Comment: Things are working fine for both increase and decrease of button width and height.

Comment: button.Width = 80; button.Height = 80; just in case you wanna reduce it to 80 square block OR button.Width = 150; button.Height = 150; in case you wanna increase it to 150 square block

Comment: But the width of button not change. :S

                Button button = new Button();
                button.Tag = (char)(key + i);

                button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
                button.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                button.FontSize = 20;
                button.Width = 40;
                button.Height = 60;
                button.Content = (char)(key + i);
                button.Click += ButtonTap;

Comment: i did the same thing as u said and it is working for me... i think u are doing something wrong in your XAML... code behind seems to be good.

Comment: I found the error. The MinWidth of Button was set 100...
Thank you for the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to cast sender to controll and get its Text property

```
var textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
if(textBlock!=null) {
    var text = textBlock.Text;
}
```